# Standard way to share state machine between two languages?

Tags: ruby, serialization, state-machine

Is there a standard way to share state-machines (that is share the machine and synchronize it's state) between two languages? I'm using the `state_machine` gem on a server and I need to synchronize the machine with another server that will be written in another language. Is there a standard way of accomplishing this so that I can maximize compatibility despite not knowing the other language? At this point, I'm thinking I'm just going to make my own "protocol" built with REST requests and sharing the initial machine structure using serialization.

I would accept "there is no standard way" as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way for doing that ...

Comment: Yeah a little bit of Googling later I figured out there's a dozen serialization methods out there (for sharing the state-machine) and communication between servers is essentially always up to the programmer.